# How to make a function with my code in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, onclick

I have a button:

```
<input onclick="if (!PreSaveItem()) return false;WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$m$g_1b663413_07f2_4335_90bd_e843be587b73$ctl00$toolBarTbl$RightRptControls$ctl00$ctl00$diidIOSaveItem", "", true, "", "", false, true))" type="button" target="_self" jQuery1110039212041699899153="167" value="Save"/>
```

When I have an error on form, i remove the attr onclick.... so it wont save the page...
and when i dont have an error, i replace the attr onclick to default...
But when i do this, the onclick function is not executed....
can I declare a function with the my code in a variable?
like this:

```
var onClickBtn = $( 'input' ).attr( 'onclick' );
function myFunc = onClickBtn;
myFunc();
```

Comment: You can also consider using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

Comment: Why not just use an event handler with a condition that fails if there are errors ?

Comment: cause its sharepoint, so i dont have a choice... this is the function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do almost that :

```
var onClickBtn = $( 'input' ).attr( 'onclick' );
var myFunc = new Function(onClickBtn);
myFunc();
```

But here it's simpler to do

```
var myFunc = $( 'input' )[0].onclick;
myFunc();
```

The difference is that in the second case you get the value of `onclick` (which is a function) instead of getting the string returned by `attr`.

**BUT :**

This answers the question that is asked. But taking the event handler from the element to execute it is such a bad practice it's awkward. You really should change your approach to the problem (which is unclear).

Comment: Thanks @dystroy
i know its not the better way, but i have no choice... this is Sharepoint, and this is the function... i cant make a function...

Answer (score 2):

It is not a good idea to use the `onclick` attribute at all. Much better is defining the function in your code and then attaching a event handler with jQuery:

```
function onClickBtn () {
    // ...
}

$('input').on('click', onClickBtn);

onClickBtn();
```